# Cannot run pip/pip3 command OS X

Tags: python, macos, scikit-learn, pip

When trying to install scikit-learn I encountered an error:

```
$ pip3 install scikit-learn
-bash: pip3: command not found here

$ pip install scikit-learn
-bash: pip3.4: command not found
```

How do I resolve this? I've already tried uninstalling pip and reinstalling it via python3, but nothing seems to work.

Pip3, however, does still seem to be installed on my machine:

```
$ locate pip3
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-pip/files/pip33
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-pip/files/pip34
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/bin/pip3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/bin/pip3.4
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/bin/pip3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/bin/pip3.5
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/pip3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/pip3.5
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3.5
```

Comment: What's the output of $PATH?

Comment: `$ $PATH
-bash: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin: No such file or directory`

Comment: It seems pip is not in any of those locations, I guess that would be the reason.

Comment: try to run `/usr/local/bin/pip3 install scikit-learn` and see if that works. Possibly omit `3` if python3 what is called when you run `python`.

Comment: `$ /usr/local/bin/pip install scikit-learn
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory`
$ /usr/local/bin/pip3 install scikit-learn
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip3: No such file or directory`

Comment: It looks like you have `/usr/local/bin/pip3` but not `/usr/local/bin/pip`. Using the former should work. `python -m pip install` is probably the best method, though; this will make sure that you're using the right `pip` for your `python`.